# OpenAL error 40963 while loading WAV file

Tags: c++, c, audio, openal

I am having an issue loading a WAV file in OpenAL. I have a function that opens the file data and casts it to a header struct. Because I know the alignment of data, I simply cast the data pointer as my data header aligned struct.

The issue is that I cannot figure out why it is throwing me 40963. If the header data in the file is correct, I must be doing something wrong with the `alBufferData`. I haven't used OpenAL until now, so I might be doing something obviously wrong.

Here is my code:

`WAV_HEADER`

```
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t Chunk_ID;
    uint32_t ChunkSize;
    uint32_t Format;

    uint32_t SubChunk1ID;
    uint32_t SubChunk1Size;
    uint16_t AudioFormat;
    uint16_t NumberOfChanels;
    uint32_t SampleRate;
    uint32_t ByteRate;

    uint16_t BlockAlignment;
    uint16_t BitsPerSecond;

    uint32_t SubChunk2ID;
    uint32_t SubChunk2Size;

    //Everything else is data. We note it's offset
    char data[];

} WAV_HEADER;
#pragma pack()
```

WAV file loader Loader

```
WAV_HEADER* loadWav(const char* filePath)
{
    long size;
    WAV_HEADER* header;
    void* buffer;

    FILE* file = fopen(filePath, "r");
    assert(file);

    fseek (file , 0 , SEEK_END);
    size = ftell (file);
    rewind (file);

    buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    fread(buffer, 1, size, file);

    header = (WAV_HEADER*)buffer;

    //Assert that data is in correct memory location
    assert((header->data - (char*)header) == sizeof(WAV_HEADER));

    //Extra assert to make sure that the size of our header is actually 44 bytes
    //as in the specification https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/
    assert((header->data - (char*)header) == 44);

    fclose(file);

    return header;
}
```

And the function that takes care of the rest of the setup:

```
void AudioController::OpenFile(const char* filePath)
{
    WAV_HEADER* data = loadWav(filePath);

    ALuint buffer;
    alGenBuffers(1, &buffer);

    alBufferData(buffer, data->Format, data, data->SubChunk2Size, data->ByteRate);

    ALint error;
    if ((error = alGetError()) != ALC_NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("OpenAL OPEN FILE ERROR: %d \n", error);
    }

    //Delete it for now to avoid leaks. Whether I need to delete the data here
    //I'll figure out later
    delete data;
}
```

Did I pass in something wrong into the function, or did I setup the header incorrectly?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

PS. This maybe important, here is the constructor that sets up the OpenAL environment:

```
AudioController::AudioController()
{
    //Open preffered audio device
    mDevice = alcOpenDevice(0);

    //Ensure that there is a device. If not something went wrong
    assert(mDevice);

    mContext = alcCreateContext(mDevice, 0);

    alcMakeContextCurrent(mContext);
    alcProcessContext(mContext);

    ALint error;
    if ((error = alGetError()) != ALC_NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("OpenAL CONTEXT CREATION: %d \n", error);
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of audio is in the WAV file? What codec?

Comment: Was solved for me by not setting sample rate explicitly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `format` parameter you pass to `alBufferData` is wrong. Your value is always 'WAVE', but the function expects an OpenAL format such as `AL_FORMAT_MONO16`, `AL_FORMAT_STEREO16`, ...

You should build the correct format based on data (`data->NumberOfChanels` and `data->BitsPerSecond` in your structure).

Note two errors with your header structure:

- Your field called `BitsPerSecond` is in reallity `BitsPerSample` (usually 8 or 16). see [this](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/)
- Maybe your wave file's header is in one block, but there is some files where the three "sub headers" (the blocks in differents color in this [link](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/)) are in different locations of the file. Thus you must play with the chunk size to find where the chunk header is located. Opening your file with an hexadecimal editor helps a lot to understand correct chunk loading.

Comment: You are correct. I got to that conclusion soon after, but thank for you for providing an accurate solution. I am wondering about the chunk size of the headers. If the first chunk is greater than 12 bytes, according to the `Chunk Size` field, what is in between this data? It seems like the format will read the sound data from the 44 byte mark (assuming we have continuous header), so what data is being held in between the header chucks? Is this a poorly formatted wave file or is there is a reason there is for this (since the header gives me chunk information)?

Comment: I saw some wav files with a "bext" subchunk just after the letters "WAVE", more than 600bytes long. Then come the "fmt " subchunk (and its correct information). After that, I have some other subchunks ("minf" "elm1"), and finally the "data" subchunk. Some of these subchunks are generated by some audio tools (ProTools in this file), some other are from wav format extensions such as http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_Wave_Format. If you need to support any wav file, consider handling any subchunk order. It is perfectly valid.